# Issue with Notification Manager on android

Tags: android, notifications, notify, notificationmanager

I'm trying to notify using a button, but both Notification and setLatestEventInfo is deprecated.

Two errors:

1.The constructor Notification(int, CharSequence, long) is deprecated `Notification notify = new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_more, "Hello all", System.currentTimeMillis());`

2.The method `setLatestEventInfo(Context, CharSequence, CharSequence, PendingIntent)` in the type Notification is not applicable for the arguments `(Context, CharSequence, CharSequence, Intent) notify.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, details, intent);`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NotificationManager ns = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification notify = new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_more, "Hello all", System.currentTimeMillis());
            Context context = MainActivity.this;
            CharSequence title ="you have be notified";
            CharSequence details = "Continue your work";
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
            notify.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, details, intent);
            ns.notify(0,notify);


        }
    });
}
```

API LEVELS:

```
       android:minSdkVersion="11"
       android:targetSdkVersion="17"
```

What is the alternative?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1. The constructor was deprecated in api level 11.** so you should use `Notification.Builder`.

*for e.g.*

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
     .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender.toString())
     .setContentText(subject)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
     .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
     .build();
```

**2. in your code you are passing the intent instead of pending in setLatestEventInfo**

```
....
Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        notify.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, details, pending);
        ns.notify(0,notify);
....
```

Comment: that must be the object of Bitmap class in example.

Comment: But we cannot do because of backward compatibility. our app should work on 4.0, 4.1, and 4.2.2. so i compiled it with 4.2.2 and app working on all devices,. and in manifest.xml add android:minSdkVersion="11"
       android:targetSdkVersion="17"

Answer (score 1):

```
notificationManager =
    (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   myNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
     "Notification!",
     System.currentTimeMillis());
   Context context = getApplicationContext();
   String notificationTitle = "Exercise of Notification!";
   String notificationText = "http://niravranpara.blogspot.com/";
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myBlog));
   PendingIntent pendingIntent
     = PendingIntent.getActivity(AndroidNotification.this,
       0, myIntent,
       Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
   myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
   myNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context,
      notificationTitle,
      notificationText,
      pendingIntent);
   notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Those constructor and method has been deprecated.so you should use notification builder instead.

`Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
   .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender.toString())
  .setContentText(subject)

  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
  .setLargeIcon(aBitmap) 
  .build();`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()`  try `java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()`