# Exception while creating an Android Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

In my app I construct a Notification with the following code:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_nursing)
    .setOngoing(true)
    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.feeding_in_progress));

if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    notificationBuilder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
}

Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_TAG, NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
} else {
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.getNotification());
}
```

In the Google Play console I see many exceptions logged for this line:

```
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_TAG, NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Mostly the error occure in Android 5.0 and 5.1, no problems with older versions. The stacktrace looks like:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: src.length=0 srcPos=0 dst.length=1 dstPos=0 length=1
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3326)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:178)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1547)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: src.length=0 srcPos=0 dst.length=1 dstPos=0 length=1
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(System.java:358)
    at android.util.ArrayMap.putAll(ArrayMap.java:579)
    at android.os.Bundle.putAll(Bundle.java:183)
    at android.app.Notification$Builder.build(Notification.java:3786)
```

Any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [notification guide list of required fields](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Required), you must set the content text via the [setContentText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setContentText(java.lang.CharSequence)) method. Note that this can be blank, but it needs to be set.

Answer (score 0):

Use NotificationCompat.Builder instead to make your code simpler and avoid surprises.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the method was deprecated as of API 11 as discussed below..

[Issue with Notification Manager on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15493633/issue-with-notification-manager-on-android)